# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robotlocomotion'

Tags: drake

I get an error as pointed in the title on execution of the following line:

```
from robotlocomotion import image_array_t
```

Is robotlocomotion no longer a part of drake?
I have installed drake on `ubuntu 20.04` using pip and I am running the python file from within a virtual environment as mentioned [here](https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#building-the-python-bindings). The example code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drake's build and install of the robotlocomotion [lcmtypes](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/lcmtypes) was deprecated in [v0.29.0](https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/v0.29.0.html) (April 2021), and removed as of [v0.33.0](https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/v0.33.0.html) (August 2021).

Nothing within Drake itself should be importing those types.  If you have your own uses for those types, you'll need to build them within your own project.

Drake offers `drake.lcmt_image_array` as a likely drop-in replacement.